# let arr = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'] хочу чтоб эти элементы были ключи объекта obj

Tags: javascript

```
let obj = {
    a: {},
    b: {},
    c: {},
    d: {}
}
```

Comment: `obj = arr.reduce((o, key) => {o[key] = {}; return o}, {}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

оформил решение от Yaant в виде ответа, все почести ему.

```js
let arr = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'];
let obj = arr.reduce((o, v) => {o[v] = {}; return o}, {});
console.log(obj);
```